# Howto make eclipse put XML in one line on save

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor, save

I seem to be unable to do this. When editing XML files I have to save them in a way that there are no line breaks and whitespaces between the elements.
If I work with XML files that already have that format, everything is fine. Eclipse does not alter the formatting.
When I create a new file using the editor, it is always formatted.

I agree, that it is much more readable, but unfortunately the software I use the XML file with doesn't support it any other way.

I used the search and it was suggested to go to 
`Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor`, and set `line-width` to a high value. Unfortunately this is not enough (999 seems to be the highes possible value) and the does not stop indenting etc. 
When entering 0 in the indent setting, nothing changes.

The Android XML formatter doesn't seem to support this either (http://tools.android.com/recent/xmlformatter)

Example of what I want:

When working with it I don't care how it looks (since one can use the `Design` Tab)

```
<attribute1>value</attribute1>
<attribute2>value</attribute2>
```

When looking at the source it should look like this or at least be saved like this in the end

```
<attribute1>value</attribute1><attribute2>value</attribute2>
```

Is there any way to do this?